# htaccess url rewriting question

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a site made with CodeIgniter with a WordPress site at `/blog`.

Say I create a page in WordPress that can be viewed at `/blog/my-page`.

Is it possible to rewrite the URL with .htaccess to remove the `blog` part of the URL? So I could enter my site url `/my-page` to view the page?

Comment: That's possible, but how then you will recognize which URL belongs to/should be processed by CodeIgniter and which by WordPress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the top of my head..

```
#start the engine
RewriteEngine on

#requests to www.yourpage.com/anything/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/?$ [NC]

#are sent to www.yourpage.com/blog/anything/
RewriteRule .* /blog/%1 [L]
```

Comment: thanks but how would I do it just for specific urls? I don't want to rewrite everything to blog only specific pages such as the one in my example.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(my-page)/?$`,  
`RewriteRule .* /blog/my-page [L]`

Comment: @geoffs3310
you have to make a pair for every rewrite

Comment: @boom Joking, right? It can be easily done in single line with no RewriteCond required.

Answer (score 0):

The rule below will rewrite (internal redirect) `/my-page` to `/blog/my-page`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^my-page$ /blog/my-page [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^another-page$ /blog/another-page [NC,L]
```

1. This needs to be placed in .htaccess in website root folder.
2. If you already have some rewrite rules there then this one need to be placed in appropriate place as **order of rules matters**.
3. You still *may need* configure WordPress a bit so it understands that this URL is for  him to process (WordPress may still see the original URL). I have not worked with WordPress that much to tell if this will be required (and how to do it if it is) -- but look at **Permalinks** settings.